# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule For Total Items Quantity 1

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

i need some Customize into the shopping cart rule
for ex: i want to set the 100%  discount for 1 Quantity into cart

i have created it and working fine.

but when i am try to 2nd qty into cart then Discount coupon remove automatically and remove discount on 1st qty as well.

i need set discount only for 1 qty if i will add more then discount coupon not delete from the cart

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats not issue & Its working perfect. Seems like what you wanted is not achievable by default magento. so Alternatively   you can create shopping cart rule with fixed price discount , so that discount will apply even if you add any number of items.....

Comment: Thank you for your quick response 
i  just want to do some Customization into the code 
and for fixed price rule i will added percents amount for discount?

Comment: @RakeshKumar you dont need to do any customization for this. you can create both fixed and percent discount with backend configuration..... [link1](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/Images/price-rule-shopping-cart-actions_thumb_0_0.png) & [link2](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html)

Comment: @ Baby in Magento see i want to give 100% discount on first product on whole website after that not any discount for the customer then what is the solution for that condition

Comment: @RakeshKumar  these [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54033/shopping-cart-rule-first-product-50-off-only-first-product-how-do-i) & [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/apply-discount-to-only-1-item-in-the-cart-via-shopping-cart-price-rules) may help.....

Comment: Thank you but not getting any good luck with this link can you share me other ideas?

Comment: @RakeshKumar sorry , i have no idea other than these, hope someone will help.....